# PYQT5 qlineedit doesn't show up after hiding it

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt5

Consider this toy example. I want to add a line_edit to the default matplotlib toolbar but only make it visible for the user after a certain action is performed, here it's a button click.

After I click the button line_edit doesn't show up but for some reason `isVisible()` outputs True. The same applies if line_edit is visible by default and I try to hide it with `self.line_edit.hide()`, it remains visible but `isVisible()` return False. So it kinda doesn't refresh itself.

How does this really work? Why line_edit is still hidden?  Any Suggestions?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT


class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Dummy')

        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line_edit.setVisible(False)
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        self.btn = QPushButton('Show line', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.show_line_edit)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.show()

    def show_line_edit(self):
        self.line_edit.show()
        print("self.line_edit.isVisible(): ")
        print(self.line_edit.isVisible())
        self.line_edit.setFocus()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You are not adding the `QLineEdit` to the layout. Just saying.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta i am adding it to the toolbar and then adding toolbar to the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationToolbar2QT` inherits from `QtWidgets.QToolBar`, and according to the [documentation of `QToolBar`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#addWidget):

> Note: You should use QAction::setVisible() to change the visibility of the widget. Using QWidget::setVisible(), QWidget::show() and QWidget::hide() does not work.

So, to get around this you could do something like

```
def initUI(self):

    ....

    self.line_edit = QLineEdit(self)
    self.line_edit.setVisible(False)
    self.line_action = self.toolbar.addWidget(self.line_edit)

    ....

def show_line_edit(self):
    self.line_action.setVisible(True)
    ....
```